# Memory leak in infinite loop in Clojure

Tags: heroku, memory-leaks, clojure

I have the following function:

```
(defn- clock-process [every f]
  (while true
  (f)
  (Thread/sleep every)))
```

And I'm spinning it off in to its own thread, to avoid blocking the main thread:

```
(future
  (clock-process 3600000 ;; fire every hour
    #(intensive-fn ...)))
```

On a Heroku dyno, total memory use is substantially growing at each hour interval:

[image]

Where the memory drops off is where the application is restarted.

Can anyone help me understand what's happening?

Comment: Thanks for responding. This is, indeed, unusual for any app I've deployed to Heroku. That the memory use increases regularly with each hour interval (each time the anonymous function is fired), seems to me I'm doing _something_ wrong... Annnnd the [R14 errors](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r14-memory-quota-exceeded)...

Comment: A lot could depend on the function you are calling. A very common issue which can appear to be a memory leak is to have a function which uses a lazy sequence, but somewhere you have  something which hangs on to the head of that sequence. This will prevent the values which are realised when the sequence is processed from being freed and will result in increased memory usage as more and more of the sequence values are realised.  Maybe post your 'intensieve-function or try using a different function.

Comment: I agree with Tim - the leak is probably due to some implementation detail of the function being called, not the loop itself. Another common culprit of memory leaks in long-running applications is memoization.

Comment: Great thoughts. I was convinced I didn't understand how infinite loops affected memory management in the JVM. I'll open up the function and report back.

Comment: K, Tim X, you were right: the memory leak was indeed inside the anonymous function. You interested in posting an answer, and I'll give you credit?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough to help you understand why this is happening, but I can suggest some options for mitigating the problem.

tl;dr: Lowering you heap size is probably the best thing to do.

First, set up the [Memory logging agent](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues#memory-logging-agent). This will periodically print some messages to the logs like:

```
source=web.1 measure.mem.jvm.heap.used=33M measure.mem.jvm.heap.committed=376M measure.mem.jvm.heap.max=376M
source=web.1 measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.used=19M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.committed=23M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.max=219M
source=web.1 measure.threads.jvm.total=21 measure.threads.jvm.daemon=11 measure.threads.jvm.nondaemon=1 measure.threads.jvm.internal=9
```

From this, you'll be able to determine where growth occurs (i.e. heap or non-heap).

If you find that the growth is all heap, you should try setting your Maximum heap size (i.e. `-Xmx`). lower than the defaults. Something like `-Xmx300m` should be sufficient, but you can probably go lower. You could also generate some heap dumps, and analyze them with a tool like [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) if you want to pinpoint the source.

If you find that growth is in non-heap, then use some of the other steps described in the [troubleshooting guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues) to determine if it's Metaspace or something else. If it is not in Metaspace, then you may have a native memory leak, which can result from leaving file handles or buffers open.

Have you tried to reproduce the problem locally? If you do so, if will be easier to dig a little deeper using tools like VisualVM and `jmap`.

Finally, you can open a [support ticket with Heroku](http://help.heroku.com). They can look at things like `smaps` to help with non-heap/native-memory leaks.